# SSIS package getting executed successfully without implementing the logic

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a packge that was completing succesfully without throwing errors when executed. But it is not implementing the logic. The data is not flowing. Even the control flow is also not getting implemented. The execution results shows everything got validated.

But it is throwing following warning message.

**BIDS Helper had problems highlighting expressions and configurations: Object reference not sent to an instance of object.**

Can anyone please suggest me what could be the reason for this.

Comment: Sounds like your package file got corrupted somehow.  You could try searching the file for an object reference that doesn't have an actual object associated with it.   Otherwise, just re-build your package from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

BIDS Helper is an Add-In - you can disable it temporarily from the Visual Studio menu: Tools / Add-In Manager.

If that avoids your issue, then I would check if you have the latest version of BIDS Helper installed.